# How to make a TextBox to take input starting with a lower case letter?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 Application.

I have a TextBox in it.

```
<TextBox />
```

As soon as I tap on the TextBox I want the normal alphabet layout to open but with the first letter starting with lowercase unlike default which starts with uppercase. I tried changing various InputScopes. It didn't work. Am I doing something wrong.

I would be glad if someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 8):

You may use:

```
<TextBox IsTextPredictionEnabled="False" IsSpellCheckEnabled="False"/>
```

As it is said [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn792128.aspx):

> Auto-capitalization: enabled if `IsSpellCheckEnabled = true`, disabled if `IsSpellCheckEnabled = false`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I couldn't relate capitalization to spell checking. MS could have done this in a better way I guess. But this worked. Thanks again.

Comment: IsTextPredictionEnabled="False" is not required right?

Comment: @vivekp It depends on you - try it. When prediction is enabled it will show some words with capitalized letter - for example names.

Comment: Got it. I was just saying that wouldn't be a required field if I just wanted to have lower case.